# Prevent enter default keyboard event in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

We've been busy with upgrading TinyMCE from 3.x to 4.2.5 and can not prevent the default `ENTER` action from happening.

Our goal is to submit the form when `CTRL + enter` is pressed, and important is that the submit should happen before the newline is added to TinyMCE. The `3.x` branch allowed us to add the event to the top of the queue:

```
// Important: inject new eventHandler via addToTop to prevent other events
tinymce.get('tinymce_instance').onKeyDown.addToTop(function(editor, event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("form").submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Unfortunately we can not figure out how to add it to the top of the events again.

`event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` do not have the expected effect because the enter is already there. The weird thing is that it does work on other keys, the alphanumeric keys can be prevented. http://jsfiddle.net/zgdcg0cj/

The event can be added using the following snippet:

```
tinymce.get('tinymce_instance').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("form").submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Problem:** the newline is added to the TinyMCE content earlier as our event handler is called, so an unwanted enter is stored. How can I add the event to the top in the `4.x` branch, or prevent the newline from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` works when you attach the keydown event via the `setup` on the `init` function.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector:'textarea',
  setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('keydown',function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13){
            alert("CTRL + ENTER PRESSED");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
  }
});
```

This does block the carriage return from happening. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksybLx7b/)

**Edit:**

Above is one way of doing it, I have found another way of achieving the result which doesn't require the `init` at all. Instead we create a new Editor instance and bind to our textarea given it has an `id`.

HTML

```
<form>
    <!--Select by ID this time -->
    <textarea id='editor_instance_1'>A different way</textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
var ed = new tinymce.Editor('editor_instance_1', {
    settings: "blah blah"
}, tinymce.EditorManager);

//attach keydown event to the editor
ed.on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13){
        alert("CTRL + ENTER");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

//render the editor on screen
ed.render();
```

Comment: Works nice! So it isn't possible to fix that outside `setup`?

Comment: Appears that it only works for the enter key when binded via the `setup` function.

Comment: Sample doesn't work ... I hit ctrl+Enter, but text still got moved to next line ...

Comment: @user2846569 What browser are you using? Are there any errors in the console? Does the alert box trigger?

Comment: Chrome on Mac ... no errors ... yes alert got opened

Comment: Try comment out the alert box or replace with `console.log`.

Comment: I don't have access to the editor instance and am trying to use the bottom method via tinyMCE.activeEditor.on but it's not working. It prevents all input EXCEPT enter. Any ideas?

Comment: PalinDrome555 is correct here I had my events added in the init_instance_callback this didn't work but changed it to setup and it now stops the enter key

Comment: if instead of using the keydown event I use the tiny NewBlock event, then preventDefault() doesn't work. Any idea why? (the event is described here https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/)

Comment: If you don't want to use setup argument, but want to add listener later you can prepend it and it will work same as doing listener attachment inside `setup`. Example: `editor.on("keydown", (e) => {e.preventDefault()}, true /* prepends */)`

Answer (score 2):

```
var init {
    ...,
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey && 13 === e.keyCode) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("form").submit();
            }
        });
};

tinymce.init(init);
```

Works for tinyMCE 4.x

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late, but this answer is for those who cannot(or don't want to) change init setup for tinymce. I found following method:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('id_of_editor_iframe');
var iframeDocument = fr.contentWindow.document;
iframeDocument.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (
        [38, 40, 13].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1 //Enter and up/down arrows or whatever you want
    ) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // your code here
        return false;
    }
}, true);
```

It helped me to prevent new line in editor